# Can you draw SVGs onto a canvas in Safari using drawImage?

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, cross-browser, compatibility

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_drawimage_svgimageelement_source_image), using an `SVGImageElement` as the parameter to a `context.drawImage` call is supported in every browser except Safari.

However, it seems like many people are using a canvas to draw SVGs in Safari?

For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385534/safari-incorrectly-drawing-shadows-on-svgs-via-html5-canvas) seems to be drawing images (granted the shadows are slightly messed up).

So, can you draw SVGs on a canvas in Safari?

Is it simply that `SVGImageElement` is not supported, but a regular `Image` is, and you can simply set the `src` on an image to an `svg`, and then it works fine?

If that is indeed the case, then does it really matter that `SVGImageElement` is not supported in Safari? You can still draw SVGs onto the canvas regardless by just using a regular Image and setting the src to be an svg asset file?

Do I have that right?

Lastly, `Path2D` seems to have full browser support, but it is a bit more cumbersome to use. Is there any advantage to using `ctx.fill(path2D)` as opposed to an `Image` with an svg as its `src`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's only `SVGImageElement` (svg:`<image>`) as **source** for `drawImage(source,...)` that they don't support. You can very well use an `HTMLImageElement` (html:`<img>`) that does point to an SVG document, even in Safari.

As for `Path2D` vs `drawImage()`, the former will allow you to draw your shape as part of the context's path drawing operation, using directly all the context's options like `fillStyle`, `lineWidth`, dash-offsets, etc. You can even use it directly with methods like `isPointInPath()`, or `clip()` etc.
On the other hand using `drawImage()` with an SVG document, you get only the pixel data of the original SVG document, it basically becomes a simple raster image. So you are limited to composite operations and filters if you want to edit the image. On a lesser level it also becomes an asynchrnous operation to draw it, since you need to wait for the image has loaded. However it allows you to have much more complex graphics than simple `<path>` data.

So my personal preference would be to use `Path2D` where you only need simple path data with great flexibility (for instance stored as JSON) and SVG documents for complex graphics that won't change, but that's just personal tastes, you may verg well be fine with only SVG documents too.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks! That just about answered everything for me.